# Import large amounts of data from Excel file into SQL Server using .NET Core and Angular

Tags: sql-server, excel, .net-core

I want to import data from Excel files into SQL Server. The size of the file is 22 MB and contains approximately 1 million rows, but I get the error timeout.

This is the code of my controller

```
[System.Web.Http.Route("UploadExcel")]
[System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
[RequestFormLimits(MultipartBodyLengthLimit = 409715200)]
[RequestSizeLimit(409715200)]
public string ExcelUpload()
{
        string message = "";
        HttpResponseMessage result = null;
        var httpRequest = HttpContext.Current.Request;

        using (AngularDBEntities objEntity = new AngularDBEntities())
        {
            if (httpRequest.Files.Count > 0)
            {
                HttpPostedFile file = httpRequest.Files[0];
                Stream stream = file.InputStream;

                IExcelDataReader reader = null;

                if (file.FileName.EndsWith(".xls"))
                {
                    reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateBinaryReader(stream);
                }
                else if (file.FileName.EndsWith(".xlsx"))
                {
                    reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(stream);
                }
                else
                {
                    message = "This file format is not supported";
                }

                DataSet excelRecords = reader.AsDataSet();
                reader.Close();

                var finalRecords = excelRecords.Tables[0];

                for (int i = 0; i < finalRecords.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    UserDetail objUser = new UserDetail();
                    objUser.UserName = finalRecords.Rows[i][0].ToString();
                    objUser.EmailId = finalRecords.Rows[i][1].ToString();
                    objUser.Gender = finalRecords.Rows[i][2].ToString();
                    objUser.Address = finalRecords.Rows[i][3].ToString();
                    objUser.MobileNo = finalRecords.Rows[i][4].ToString();
                    objUser.PinCode = finalRecords.Rows[i][5].ToString();

                    objEntity.UserDetails.Add(objUser);
                }

                int output = objEntity.SaveChanges();

                if (output > 0)
                {
                    message = "Excel file has been successfully uploaded";
                }
                else
                {
                    message = "Excel file uploaded failed";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                result = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
        }

        return message;
    }
```

I added `maxRequestLength="1048576" executionTimeout="999999"` to the `web.config` file in the `system.web` section, and `maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824"` to security tag, but I am still facing this problem.

Knowing that when I upload small files, the data is added to the table

Comment: Try to increase timeout in connection string of DB

Answer (score 0):

you can add all items in a list and finally use **bulk insert**. use can use [Entity Framework Extensions](https://entityframeworkcore.com/saving-data-bulk-insert).